# How to deal with NSData contentsOfURL EXC_BREAKPOINT error

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

I am trying to obtain NSData from a server using contentsOfURL. When the iPhone is connected to wifi, it works fine. But when not connected to wifi, my app crashes with an EXC_BREAKPOINT message. How can I handle or circumvent this issue of crashing when not connected?

```
do {
    let varOption = try NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!, options:NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
} catch {
    print("error encountered")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `urlToRequest` nil?

Comment: Hi JAL. Thanks for the thought. No. If wifi is connected, this code works fine. IE, urltorequest does not suddenly become nil when wifi is not connected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a requirement to use `NSData`'s `contentsOfURL`?  Why not make an async web request using `NSURLSession`?

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!) { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // if data && !error, do the thing
}.resume()
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, NSData contentsOfURL is deprecated anyway. NSURLSession worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tutorial to create a function to check if iPhone is connected to Internet.

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-check-for-internet-connection-in-swift/

After implementing this function you can use it to validate the connection and then put your code inside an **if** statement block

```
if isConnectedToNetwork() {   //<-- This is the function implemented in tutorial posted before.

    //Here we put your code
    do {
        let varOption = try NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!, options:NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
    } catch {
        print("error encountered")
    }

}
```